# getViewLifecycleOwner() in DialogFragment leads to crash

Tags: android, viewmodel, dialogfragment, android-livedata

I use `DialogFragment (onCreateDialog)` and ViewModel for it. But, when I try to pass `getViewLifecycleOwner()` to the `LiveData::observe` method I get the error below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView().
```

Is it possible to use `getViewLifecycleOwner()` inside a `DialogFragment`?

Comment: In `onCreateDialog` Dialog is creating not yet created . Try in `onViewCreated()`. I myself not much used `LifecycleOwner`.

Answer (score 19):

[This is the official recommendation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs#lifecycle) for `DialogFragment`s:

> **Note:** When subscribing to lifecycle-aware components such as `LiveData`, you should never use `viewLifecycleOwner` as the `LifecycleOwner` in a `DialogFragment` that uses `Dialogs`. Instead, use the `DialogFragment` itself, or if you're using Jetpack Navigation, use the `NavBackStackEntry`.

So you can just observe things as normal, but instead of `viewLifecycleOwner` you pass `this`, or the current backstack entry (e.g. `findNavController().currentBackStackEntry`). No need to override `onCreateView` just to force a `viewLifecycleOwner` to be created or anything!

Answer (score 16):

This happens because of how the DialogFragment is created.
If you use `onCreateDialog()` than a slightly different lifecycle is used for this type of Fragment. The `onCreateView()` will not be used, thus the `viewLifecycleOwner` for this Fragment won't be initialized.

As a workaround for this, you can use the Fragment instance as the owner for the observer:
`.observe(this, Observer {...}`. Although you will get a warning for using `this` instead of the `viewLifecycleOwner`.

Comment: I seem to get no warning using `this` (MyDialogFragment). Is this approach preferable to using either `getActivity()` or `requireActivity()`?

Comment: @ban-geoengineering As long as you don't `show` the DialogFragment multiple times with the same fragment instance. If you do, observers will be subscribed on a second time and you might have weird issues due to double observation. That's because by using `this` as the lifecycle owner, observers are only removed when `onDestroy` is called, and it isn't called by simply dismissing the dialog.

Answer (score 8):

Your case is slightly different but I think the concept is kind of the same. Just use *`this.getActivity()`* in your Dialog Class and pass it as *`LifeCycleOwner`*. I had the same problem because I used *`LiveData`* and *`Retrofit`* and `LiveData` needs a reference. The *`DialogFragment`* sets its *`LifeCycleOwner`* at some point but it is not at any of the methods mentioned above. By using the *`getActivity()`* you can use your observer as early as in onCreateDialog method. Here is some portion of my code that at first caused some issue when I tried to pass a null referenced *`this.getViewLifecycleOwner()`* instead of the activity.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       FragmentActivity activity = this.getActivity();
       binding = DialogSelectIssuesBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()));

       RetroRepository.
            getDefault().
            getAllIssues().
            observe(this.getActivity(), listLiveDataResponse -> {
                //ToDo Check for errors and Bind the data here 
            });


       AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                            .setView(binding.getRoot())
                            .setTitle("Please select issues from the list below:")
                            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null)
                            .setPositiveButton("ADD", null)
                            .create();
       alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
       return alertDialog;
}
```

Comment: What if fragment is destroyed then recreated, but the activity isn't? Old observers still reference the old fragment, and you got yourself a memory leak! The whole point of `viewLifecycleOwner` is to remove the observers when the fragment is destroyed.

Answer (score 7):

this happens because the lifecycle of `DialogFragment` is different from `Fragment`; `onCreateDialog` is called before `onCreateView`, so `viewLifecycleOwner` is unavailable... I worked around the issue by:

- implemeting `onCreateView` instead of `onCreateDialog`

  - can access `viewLifecycleOwner` from within `onCreateView`
  - view returned from `onCreateView` is put into a dialog for us by `DialogFragment`...
  - you will need to create your own buttons, and titles in the dialog...

supplemental code:

```
class TextInputDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    ...

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val viewBinding = FragmentDialogTextInputBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        val titleText = params.title.localize(requireContext())
        viewBinding.toolbar.isVisible = titleText.isNotBlank()
        if (titleText.isNotBlank()) {
            viewBinding.toolbar.title = titleText
        }

        viewBinding.recyclerview.adapter = ListItemAdapter(
            viewLifecycleOwner, requireContext().app.nowFactory, viewModel.fields
        )

        viewBinding.buttonAffirm.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onOkPressed(viewModel.userInputtedText.value)
            dismiss()
        }

        viewBinding.buttonReject.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }

        viewModel.enablePositiveButton.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { isEnabled ->
            viewBinding.buttonAffirm.isEnabled = isEnabled
        }

        return viewBinding.root
    }

    ...
}
```

the layout file used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            tools:title="Title" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

        <LinearLayout
            style="?buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/min_touch_target_spacing_half">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_reject"
                style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/min_touch_target_spacing_half"
                android:text="@android:string/cancel" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_affirm"
                style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/min_touch_target_spacing_half"
                android:text="@android:string/ok" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was a little bit wacky...

My component was using the getViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData() .... so:

```
private final MyLifeCycleOwner owner = new MyLifeCycleOwner();

private final MutableLiveData<LifecycleOwner> result = new MutableLiveData<>();

@NonNull
@Override
public LiveData<LifecycleOwner> getViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData() {
    return result;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    owner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY);
    result.setValue(null);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    result.setValue(owner);
    owner.getLifecycle();
    owner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Because FragmentViewLifecycleOwner is package private ... that's the reason for the MyLifeCycleOwner class.

I was not gonna change my components because of some mismanagement on the android architecture...

Answer (score 0):

Because `DialogFragment` pops over the view of a parent fragment it can use its lifecycle owner. Thus code will look like this:

```
parentFragment?.viewLifecycleOwner?.let {
    binding.lifecycleOwner = it
}
```